# okhttp3 error: Jenkins master loses connection to agents

Tags: java, jenkins, openshift, okhttp

I am running a Jenkins Master/Controller, which is connected to several agents,the number of them is depending on the workload. I use openshift to manage this.
Installed Jenkins Plugins (among others) are: okhttp-api:4.9.3-105.vb96869f8ac3a, github, blueocean,...
Mainly Java Applications are running on the machines.

Randomly, I get the following error:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: '**okhttp3.OkHttpClient**
> io.fabric8.openshift.client.DefaultOpenShiftClient.getHttpClient()'
> at
> io.fabric8.jenkins.openshiftsync.OpenShiftUtils.initializeOpenShiftClient(OpenShiftUtils.java:153)
> at
> io.fabric8.jenkins.openshiftsync.GlobalPluginConfiguration.start(GlobalPluginConfiguration.java:128)
> at
> io.fabric8.jenkins.openshiftsync.GlobalPluginConfiguration.configChange(GlobalPluginConfiguration.java:123)
> at
> io.fabric8.jenkins.openshiftsync.GlobalPluginConfiguration.(GlobalPluginConfiguration.java:111)
> at
> io.fabric8.jenkins.openshiftsync.GlobalPluginConfiguration$$FastClassByGuice$$-1829337750.GUICE$TRAMPOLINE()
> at
> io.fabric8.jenkins.openshiftsync.GlobalPluginConfiguration$$FastClassByGuice$$-1829337750.apply()
> at
> com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$FastClassProxy.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:82)
> at
> com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:114)
> at
> com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.access$000(ConstructorInjector.java:33)
> at
> com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector$1.call(ConstructorInjector.java:98)
> at
> com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:109)
> at
> hudson.ExtensionFinder$GuiceFinder$SezpozModule.onProvision(ExtensionFinder.java:568)
> at
> com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:117)
> at
> com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:66)
> at
> com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:93)
> at
> com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:296)
> at
> com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
> Caused: com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see
> the following errors:
>
> 1. 'okhttp3.OkHttpClient DefaultOpenShiftClient.getHttpClient()'   at
>    GlobalPluginConfiguration.(GlobalPluginConfiguration.java:109)

If I run into this error, my Jenkins controller can not connect to his agents anymore.
Any idea wherer this comes from and why? Unfortunately, I can not just uninstall the okhttp Plugin, as it is depending on 2 others I need: github and blueocean...
Another hint: Before this error occurs, I get several 'Failed to start thread - warnings:

```
failed to start thread - pthread_create failed (EAGAIN) for attributes: stacksize: 512k, guardsize: 0k, detached.
2022-05-24 09:11:36.768+0000 [id=26197] INFO    o.c.j.p.k.KubernetesSlave#deleteSlavePod: Terminated Kubernetes instance for agent bmf-central-ci-prod/generaljdk8-fabe-gj02j
2022-05-24 09:11:36.768+0000 [id=26197] INFO    o.c.j.p.k.KubernetesSlave#_terminate: Disconnected computer generaljdk8-fabe-gj02j
2022-05-24 09:11:36.769+0000 [id=26133] INFO    j.s.DefaultJnlpSlaveReceiver#channelClosed: Computer.threadPoolForRemoting [#561] for generaljdk8-fabe-gj02j terminated: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
2022-05-24 09:11:36.771+0000 [id=25980] INFO    o.j.p.workflow.job.WorkflowRun#finish: fabe/FABE DWH/fabe-st/feature%2F388355-Strafverfuegung-auf-Prod #1 completed: SUCCESS
2022-05-24 09:11:36.996+0000 [id=26921] INFO    i.f.j.o.BuildSyncRunListener#onStarted: Run started: Fallbearbeitung (FABE) » FABE » fabe-st » feature/388355-Strafverfuegung-auf-Prod #2
2022-05-24 09:11:36.996+0000 [id=26921] INFO    i.f.j.o.BuildSyncRunListener#onStarted: Not polling polling build job/fabe/job/FABE%20DWH/job/fabe-st/job/feature%252F388355-Strafverfuegung-auf-Prod/2/ as its not a WorkflowJob
2022-05-24 09:11:37.236+0000 [id=26921] INFO    o.j.p.workflow.job.WorkflowRun#finish: fabe/FABE DWH/fabe-st/feature%2F388355-Strafverfuegung-auf-Prod #2 completed: FAILURE
[18664.801s][warning][os,thread] Failed to start thread - pthread_create failed (EAGAIN) for attributes: stacksize: 512k, guardsize: 0k, detached.
2022-05-24 09:11:49.797+0000 [id=26448] INFO    o.c.j.p.k.KubernetesLauncher#launch: Waiting for agent to connect (60/1,000): general-s8fd4
[18676.187s][warning][os,thread] Failed to start thread - pthread_create failed (EAGAIN) for attributes: stacksize: 512k, guardsize: 0k, detached.
[18676.197s][warning][os,thread] Failed to start thread - pthread_create failed (EAGAIN) for attributes: stacksize: 512k, guardsize: 0k, detached.
[18676.206s][warning][os,thread] Failed to start thread - pthread_create failed (EAGAIN) for attributes: stacksize: 512k, guardsize: 0k, detached.
2022-05-24 09:11:54.287+0000 [id=21885] WARNING n.u.l.h.p.g.GitParameterDefinition#getTag: [ bmf-sa-pruefverwaltung/test ]  Download tags from the repository failed
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create native thread: possibly out of memory or process/resource limits reached
```

Only thing what helped so far was to restart the Jenkins Controller Pod manually :-/
Even changing the ThreadStackSize did just reduce the occurance of the error, but not resolve it.

Happy for any hints, thanks a lot in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

How are your Jenkins resourses doing? You may want to bump up your resource limits and requests in Openshift based off the message `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create native thread: possibly out of memory`